# Registry value returns null when key has spaces uwing WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

When trying to retrieve the value of a registry key from a remote machine for a key that has spaces using WMI in C# (Reason for using WMI: Authentication and Impersonation needed), the GetStringValue returns null but when the key doesn't have spaces, it works perfectly. Using either the @ notation or standard " notation for strings didn't help. I tried enclosing the key in double-quotes. Didn't help either.

Here's the code I have written:

```
public static string GetRemoteRegistryValue(string MachineName, string username, string password)
{
    string regValue = string.Empty;
    ConnectionOptions opt = new ConnectionOptions();

    opt.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    opt.EnablePrivileges = true;
    opt.Username = username;
    opt.Password = password;
    opt.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    opt.EnablePrivileges = true;
    try
    {
        ManagementPath p = new ManagementPath("\\\\" + MachineName + "\\root\\cimv2");

        ManagementScope msc = new ManagementScope(p, opt);
        msc.Connect();

        string softwareRegLoc = "\"SOFTWARE\\VMware, Inc.\\VMware Drivers\"";
        //string softwareRegLoc = @"""SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Suite XI 4.0\Config Manager""";

        ManagementClass registry = new ManagementClass(msc, new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), null);
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
        inParams["hDefKey"] = 0x80000002;//HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
        inParams["sSubKeyName"] = softwareRegLoc;
        inParams["sValueName"] = "VmciHostDevInst";

        // Read Registry Key Names 
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, null);
        if (outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value != null)
        {
            regValue = outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value.ToString();
        }

    }
    catch (ManagementException Ex)
    {
    }
    catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException Ex)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
    }
    return regValue;
}
```

What is the solution for this issue?

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio installed at the moment, so can't check this: have you tried underscores?

Comment: Do those exceptions tell you anything?

Comment: @LarsTech the outParams.Properties return value is 2, there is no exception

Comment: @AStopher I havent found a key which has underscores in the registry. Hence I havent tried yet.

Comment: @AshwinHariharan I meant in place of the spaces (so "VMware, Inc." would be "VMware,_Inc." for instance). No idea if it would work though.

Comment: @AStopher this didnt work. the return value is still 2, and registry key value is null

Comment: @AshwinHariharan: Have you tried `softwareRegLoc = "SOFTWARE\\VMware, Inc.\\VMware Drivers"`. I think that he searches for the key **"SOFTWARE\\VMware, Inc.\\VMware Drivers"** including the Quotation marks

Comment: @ThomasVoß I have tried with and without quotation marks. Neither of the methods worked

Comment: `the return value is still 2, and registry key value is null`  It sounds like it worked.  It found something.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, two points here:

1. You shouldn't use quotation marks. So, replace `"\"SOFTWARE\\VMware, Inc.\\VMware Drivers\""` with `"SOFTWARE\\VMware, Inc.\\VMware Drivers"`.
2. The path that you're trying to access belongs to the 64-bit provider. In order to be able to access it (by default), your application needs to have its Platform Target set to `x64`. Otherwise, your application would be trying to access the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\VMware, Inc.\VMware Drivers` path, which probably doesn't exist.

Removing the quotation marks and targeting `x64` worked just fine for me and I got the value of the exact path mentioned in the question.

If your Platform Target is set to `x86` (or `Any CPU` with the `Prefer 32-bit` checkbox ticked) and you don't want to change it to `x64`, then you have to force WMI to access the 64-bit Registry Hive. Check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/requesting-wmi-data-on-a-64-bit-platform) for more info.

Here's a full example:

```
public static string GetRemoteRegistryValue(string MachineName, string username, string password)
{
    string regValue = string.Empty;
    ConnectionOptions opt = new ConnectionOptions();

    opt.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    opt.EnablePrivileges = true;
    opt.Username = username;
    opt.Password = password;
    opt.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    opt.EnablePrivileges = true;
    try
    {
        ManagementPath p = new ManagementPath("\\\\" + MachineName + "\\root\\cimv2");

        ManagementScope msc = new ManagementScope(p, opt);
        msc.Connect();

        string softwareRegLoc = "SOFTWARE\\VMware, Inc.\\VMware Drivers";

        ManagementClass registry = new ManagementClass(msc, new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), null);
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
        inParams["hDefKey"] = 0x80000002;//HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
        inParams["sSubKeyName"] = softwareRegLoc;
        inParams["sValueName"] = "VmciHostDevInst";

        ManagementNamedValueCollection objCtx = new ManagementNamedValueCollection();
        objCtx.Add("__ProviderArchitecture", 64);
        objCtx.Add("__RequiredArchitecture", true);
        InvokeMethodOptions options = new InvokeMethodOptions(objCtx, TimeSpan.MaxValue);

        // Read Registry Key Names 
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, options);
        if (outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value != null)
        {
            regValue = outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (ManagementException Ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException Ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return regValue;
}
```

The code above returned the value of `VmciHostDevInst` while the app is targeting `x86`.